# Magento Compilation Not enabling in Admin panel

Tags: magento

I have tried to enable **"Compilation"** in Magento admin panel. When I click enable button it shows "**Compiler include path is enabled**" meassage, But magento "**Compiler Status**" shows "**Disable"** and button shows "**Enable**" option in top right.

How to fix this issue in admin panel? Please suggest me to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions on `includes/` is most likely invalid for the web server to write to it.

When enabling/disabling the compiler `includes/config.php` file is modified, if setting proper permissions doesn't work try commenting out the two `require` statements in the `config.php` file.

Comment: Shall i mount the file permission (777) for include folder and config.php ?

Comment: @Man Kingdom I wouldn't  - to be safe, either change ownership of the include directory to that of your web server or set the group permissions so that the web server can write to it (e.g. 775 for includes, 664 for config.php)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add:

APC can prevent the compilation from being enabled by loading previously cached php files.
After setting up the permissions correctly on the includes folder, enable the cache on magento. Then restart the APC by restarting the host process.
On a Debian server with apache, run service apache2 restart.
Then refresh the screen and the compilation will be enabled.

Comment: Ah - thanks - this was it for me. Still said permissions were set incorrectly despite the contrary until restarting apache. I actually had to add the `define` statements to the config.php file.  After completing this, operation performed as it should.